# Getting Each Text Files Data Imported onto new row?

Tags: vba, excel, import

I am using the following code to scan a directory for text files.
It then imports all the data from each text file. At the moment my data is being imported scrambled with each word placed in a different row and column.

What I am wanting is each line of text per text file to be inserted into different columns in one row.

So text file 1 might contain:

```
A Cat
Mark Spence
Birmingham
```

And when imported into excel it should read:

```
A        B               C
A Cat    Mark Spence     Birmingham
```

then text file 2 would be inserted into the next row below.

so text file 2:

```
A Dog
David Gray
Manchester
```

Result:

```
A        B               C
A Cat    Mark Spence     Birmingham
A Dog    David Gray      Manchester
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong with this? Thanks

```
Sub Import_All_Text_Files_2007()

    Dim nxt_row As Long

     'Change Path
    Const strPath As String = "Z:\NS\Unactioned\"
    Dim strExtension As String

     'Stop Screen Flickering
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ChDir strPath

     'Change extension
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")

    Do While strExtension <> ""

         'Adds File Name as title on next row
        Range("A1").Value = strExtension

         'Sets Row Number for Data to Begin
        nxt_row = Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

         'Below is from a recorded macro importing a text file
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & strPath & strExtension, Destination:=Range("$A$" & nxt_row))
            .Name = strExtension
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
             'Delimiter Settings:
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "="

            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        strExtension = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Here, Destination:=Range("$A$" & nxt_row)), use nxt_col, where nxt_col is the next blank column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of QueryTables, use:

```
FileNum = FreeFile()
curCol = 1
Open strPath & strExtension For Input As #FileNum
While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
    ActiveSheet.Cells(nxt_row,curCol) = DataLine
    curCol = curCol + 1
Wend
Close #FileNum
```

I didn't test it, but it should at least guide you.

Comment: thanks for your comment, please could you show me where would I place this code within my existing code?